# How to align items on extreme left and right in react native?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native

In react native I cannot use something like `float:left` or `float:right` so I want to align items extreme left and right how can I do that? I have used absolute position on parent View but inside that View flexdirection and justify content space between is not working why so? Does flexbox and absolute positioning doesn't work together?

Code:

```
<View style={styles.cardContent}>
        <View style={{maxWidth: 175}}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: '700',
              padding: 10,
              color: 'white',
            }}>
            {hotelName}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', marginLeft: 75}}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: '700',
              padding: 5,
              textAlign: 'right',
              color: 'white',
            }}>
            &#8377; {newRate}
          </Text>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: '700',
              textAlign: 'right',
              color: 'white',
              textDecorationLine: 'line-through',
              textDecorationStyle: 'solid',
            }}>
            &#x20b9; {oldRate}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
```

CSS:

```
 cardContent: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
```

For cardContent I cannot remove position absolute and bottom 0 property because I want to fix the card at bottom of the screen.

In below screenshot you can see that hotel name is present on extreme left but newRate and oldRate is not going in extreme right even after using `flexDirection: 'row'` and `justify content: space between`

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: add width `100%`

Comment: I do not see display property in the css, Just to make sure that justify-content works properly could you add display: flex; flex-basis:100%; and min-width:100%; to the cardContent class. and check if it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```
cardContent: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor:'red',
    width:'100%' // add width 
  },
```

Comment: `justifyContent: 'space-between'` did it for me. Thanks, Nagesh.

Answer (score 1):

add a `width: '100%'` to your `cardContent` component styles.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add `width: Dimensions.get('window').width` to the `cardContent` style instead of `width: 100%`.

Since `100%` means that you want this element to fits 100% of its parent width and `Dimensions.get('window').width` means that you want the width of the viewport (device).